# Mysql trigger trouble IF ELSE UPDATE

Tags: java, mysql, if-statement, triggers, delimiter

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER agregarMateriaCurso AFTER INSERT ON MateriasDoctorado
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF (SELECT troncal FROM Materias WHERE codigo=NEW.codigoMateria)=1
        THEN
            UPDATE CursoDoctorado SET cantidadMateriasTroncales=cantidadMateriasTroncales+1 WHERE codigo=NEW.codigoDoctorado;
   ELSE
         UPDATE CursoDoctorado SET cantidadMateriasEspecificas=cantidadMateriasEspecificas+1 WHERE codigo=NEW.codigoDoctorado;
        END IF;
END;//
delimiter ;

public class Consulta {

    public static String[] triggers = {
         "delimiter // CREATE TRIGGER agregarMateriaCurso AFTER INSERT ON MateriasDoctorado    FOR EACH ROW  BEGIN  IF (SELECT troncal FROM Materias WHERE codigo=NEW.codigoMateria)=1         THEN            UPDATE CursoDoctorado SET cantidadMateriasTroncales=cantidadMateriasTroncales+1 WHERE codigo=NEW.codigoDoctorado;   ELSE         UPDATE CursoDoctorado SET cantidadMateriasEspecificas=cantidadMateriasEspecificas+1 WHERE codigo=NEW.codigoDoctorado;        END IF; END;// delimiter ;", "delimiter // CREATE TRIGGER eliminarMateriaCurso AFTER DELETE ON MateriasDoctorado   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN   IF (SELECT troncal FROM Materias WHERE codigo=OLD.codigoMateria)=1        THEN            UPDATE CursoDoctorado SET cantidadMateriasTroncales=cantidadMateriasTroncales-1 WHERE codigo=OLD.codigoDoctorado;    ELSE            UPDATE CursoDoctorado SET cantidadMateriasEspecificas=cantidadMateriasEspecificas-1 WHERE codigo=OLD.codigoDoctorado;        END IF; END;// delimiter ; "
    };
}


 for(String sentencia:Consulta.triggers){
                System.out.println(mysqli.update(sentencia));
            }
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'delimiter // CREATE TRIGGER agregarMateriaCurso AFTER INSERT ON
>   MateriasDoctorad' at line 1

Comment: What is the Java API method used to execute your SQL string `sentencia`?

Comment: is the jdbc api com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem was the missing word begin, and the second problem was the trigger insertion from java and was solved removing the "delimiter //".

Answer (score 0):

The BEGIN keyword is missed, try this query -

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER agregarMateriaCurso AFTER INSERT ON MateriasDoctorado FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT troncal FROM Materias WHERE codigo = NEW.codigoMateria) = 1 THEN
    UPDATE CursoDoctorado SET cantidadMateriasTroncales = cantidadMateriasTroncales + 1 WHERE codigo = NEW.codigoDoctorado;
  ELSE
    UPDATE CursoDoctorado SET cantidadMateriasEspecificas = cantidadMateriasEspecificas + 1 WHERE codigo = NEW.codigoDoctorado;
  END IF;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Works fine on Mysql cli, but not in java: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter // CREATE TRIGGER agregarMateriaCurso AFTER INSERT ON MateriasDoctorad' at line 1

Comment: DELIMITER is not a MySQL command, this command is used by client, e.g. MySQL command-line client. But not all clients support it. To avoid this - try to execute just CREATE TRIGGER command, without delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing BEGIN from your for loop:

```
->    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
->    IF (SELECT troncal FROM Materias WHERE codigo=NEW.codigoMateria)=1
->         THEN
->             UPDATE CursoDoctorado SET cantidadMateriasTroncales=cantidadMateriasTroncales+1 WHERE codigo=NEW.codigoDoctorado;
->    ELSE
->          UPDATE CursoDoctorado SET cantidadMateriasEspecificas=cantidadMateriasEspecificas+1 WHERE codigo=NEW.codigoDoctorado;
->         END IF;
-> END;//
```